# UICollectionViewCell: AutoLayout - incorrect size calculation (offset by exacatly 10 pt)

Tags: ios, autolayout, uikit, uicollectionviewcell, sizing

I'm having a set of *UICollectionViewCell* subclasses with different layout (using AutoLayout).

Since "Self Sizing Cells" feature is completely broken, I calculate size manually in the *DataSource*. However, I've noticed that the calculated size **is exactly 10 pt** less than it should be, regardless of the cell.

Here is the code I use to calculate size:

```
  let sizeCache = CellCache() // Size cache stores previously calculated values
  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    if let cachedSize = sizeCache.sizeAtIndexPath(indexPath: indexPath) {
      return cachedSize // Return cached value if it exists
    }

    // Calculate the size if not found in the cache
    let cellClass = cellTypeAt(indexPath: indexPath) // Get the class type
    let cell = sizeCache.createCellOfTypeIfNeeded(cellType: cellClass) // Dequeue or instantiate a cell
    self.collectionView(collectionView, cell: cell, configureAt: indexPath) // Ask DataSource to configure this cell
    let fittingSize = CGSize(width: collectionView.bounds.width - 16, height: 0) // Set the padding to 16
    cell.bounds = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: fittingSize) // Set cell's width
    var result = cell.contentView.systemLayoutSizeFitting(UIView.layoutFittingCompressedSize) // Calculate cell's size using AutoLayout
    result.width = collectionView.bounds.width - 16 // Set the padding
    result.height = result.height + 10 // !!! Error - Add 10 pt to the result !!!
    sizeCache.setSize(size: result, at: indexPath) // Cache the result
    return result
  }
```

Note the line at the end where **I have to add 10 pt** to make it work.

All my cells are a subclasses of this base class which sets the `width` constraint:

```
import UIKit
import SnapKit

class AutoSizingCellBase: UICollectionViewCell {
  override class var requiresConstraintBasedLayout: Bool {
    return true
  }

  private final var widthConstraint: Constraint?

  override func updateConstraints() {
    if widthConstraint == nil {
      if let window = window {
        let width = window.bounds.width - 16
        contentView.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
          widthConstraint = make.width.equalTo(width).constraint
        }
      }
    }
    super.updateConstraints()
  }
}
```

The examples of the issue:

**Correct sizing (after adding 10 pt)**
[image: Correct sizing (after adding 10 pt]

**Incorrect sizing (without adding 10 pt)**
[image: Incorrect sizing (without adding 10 pt)]

The issue affects all the cells. What could be the root cause of it?

**Update: Constraints Example**
Here are the constraints I use to configure the views shown:

```
  private func setupConstraints() {
    price.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(.required, for: .horizontal)
    disclosureIndicator.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(.required, for: .horizontal)
    disclosureIndicator.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(.required, for: .vertical)
    disclosureIndicator.setContentHuggingPriority(.required, for: .horizontal)
    disclosureIndicator.setContentHuggingPriority(.required, for: .vertical)

    title.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
      make.leading.top.equalTo(contentView.layoutMarginsGuide)
      make.trailing.lessThanOrEqualTo(price.snp.leading).offset(-8)
    }

    subtitle.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
      make.top.equalTo(title.snp.bottom).offset(8)
      make.leading.bottom.equalTo(contentView.layoutMarginsGuide)
    }

    disclosureIndicator.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
      make.trailing.equalTo(contentView.layoutMarginsGuide)
      make.centerY.equalToSuperview()
    }

    price.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
      make.trailing.equalTo(disclosureIndicator.snp.leading).offset(-8)
      make.centerY.equalToSuperview()
    }
  }
```

This is a rather complex example, but the issue is reproducible even with a more simpler ones:

```
  private func setupConstraints() {
    button.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
      make.width.equalToSuperview() // Button is a subview of the UIStackView
    }

    stack.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
      make.edges.equalTo(contentView.layoutMarginsGuide)
      make.height.greaterThanOrEqualTo(150)
    }
  }
```

**Update**

Adding the offset in the constraint solves the issue, while the view hierarchy debugger still shows "Ambiguous layout":

```
subtitle.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
  make.top.equalTo(title.snp.bottom).offset(8)
  make.leading.equalTo(contentView.layoutMarginsGuide)
  make.bottom.equalTo(contentView.layoutMarginsGuide).offset(-10) // Subtracted 10
}
```

The question is where does the `10` comes from is still open.

**Update 3**
It seems that a part of the problem is in adjusting the `layoutMargins`:

```
UIView.appearance().layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsets(top: 16, left: 16, bottom: 16, right: 16)
```

After I've removed the line above from the `AppDelegate`, the size calculations became correct, although the looks of the cells changed. 
So I'm thinking that the problem is for some reason the cells created for sizing have a different inset than the ones dequeued from the `UICollectionView`.

[image: Cells without insets]

Comment: Depends on what your constraints are.

Comment: Also, could this be replaced by a table view?

Comment: @matt I've updated my question with the constraints example.

Comment: @matt `UItableView` is not an option here, since the `UICollectionView` has a custom layout with shadows, headers and separators.

Comment: I think the 10 is a red herring and the heights are correct, but the top of everything is shoved down. Look at how your disclosure indicator is not vertically centered.

Comment: What did you find out when you looked at this through the View Debugger?

Comment: I'm getting "View has ambiguous layout" for pretty much every cell.

Comment: Well there’s the issue then. As I suggested, it’s the constraints.

Comment: @matt I've added next update - adding an offset to the constraint solves the issue, but I'll have to add that offset to pretty much every cell. It seems, that there is some other issue why the `10` is needed.

Comment: Maybe the layout margins are not what you think they are. Maybe the separators are being drawn in the wrong place. Hard to say from here.

Comment: @matt separators are drawn as the decoration views and aren not affecting the sizes. The issue is still present when I swap my custom layout for a default `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`LayoutMargins` are calculated differently for a `UICollectionViewCell` when added to a superview and when not in a view hierarchy.

Because of the line:

```
UIView.appearance().layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsets(top: 16, left: 16, bottom: 16, right: 16)
```

Cells added to the superview had different margins than the cells created for sizing. Hence the difference.